# Swagger-ui error HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, springfox

I am trying to add a Spring fox Swagger UI to my existing Spring Boot project.

My issue is that all the paths are working normally like "/v2/api".. except for "/swagger-ui.html". 
The error I get everytime is :

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Oct 30 11:11:37 CET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

and the error in debut :

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

When I tried to handle the exception on my Exception Handler, I found that the acceptable type is "application/json" as I use Spring MVC.

Any idea how to resolve that ?

cheers.

Comment: have you used reactive programming?

Comment: Hi, no I haven't.